# SQL Return only duplicate rows

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns the following rows:

StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId

I need to return only the rows that are exact duplicates all across the board so each record must be exctly the same as the other record for it to be a duplicate. I would like to return both records. These reocrds are mixed in with a bunch of records that do not have duplicates...

Any idea?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First, identify the duplicates. Second, join back to  extract these rows.

A non-aggregated (or non-window/ranking) self join forms a partial cross join and gives the square of duplicates for any set of keys. Including non-duplicates too. 1 x 1 = 1 after all.

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
       StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId
    FROM
       myTable
    GROUP BY
       StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId
    HAVING
       COUNT(*) >= 2
    ) T1
    JOIN
    mytable T2 ON T1.StateId = T2.StateId AND T1.OrderId = T2.OrderId AND
                   T1.OrderTime = T2.OrderTime AND T1.PermitId = T2.PermitId
```

Comment: This was a very s

Answer (score 27):

In general, if you're just trying to see what rows have duplicate for those values...

```
SELECT StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId, COUNT(*) FROM Foo
GROUP BY StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: OP explicitly stated that he/she needs both duplicate rows on the result set.

Answer (score 11):

One possibility if your database server supports subqueries:

```
select * from your_table
 where (StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId) in
  ( select StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId
      from your_table
     group by StateId, OrderId, OrderTime, PermitId
    having count(1) > 1 )
```

Comment: This would fail in some RDBMS because the IN clause has more than 1 column. Would be Ok with EXISTS or INTERSECT

Comment: OP did not state what RDBMS he/she is using. It will definitely work in some servers.

Comment: eh, what rdbms does not support IN clause with multiple columns?

Comment: @Ronnis: I think SQLServer does not support it. But PostgreSQL, MySQL and several other do.

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm using it all the time in mysql and oracle, but I only had a shorter romance with SQL Server and I guess I never used that syntax on that project.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz, @Ronnis: It's quite an ugly syntax IMHO. Better to use EXISTS or INTERSECT perhaps. And if you use NOT IN the semantics are quite different to NOT EXISTS or EXCEPT. Finally, on SQL Server, IN and EXISTS generate the same plan