# How to delete duplicates from a table and keeping only the one with highest id in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with unique ID and then some fields. I would like to delete all the dupliacte rows and keep only one, the one with highest id.

For example assuming to have a table with 3 fields: `RECORD_ID`, `FIELD_ONE`, `FIELD_TWO`

which is the query that allows me to delete all records that have same value for `FIELD_ONE` and `FIELD_TWO` except the one that has highest `RECORD_ID`?

Comment: Duplicate of [Find duplicates in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057352/find-duplicates-in-sql) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401326/sql-return-only-duplicate-rows/4401334#4401334) and many others

Answer (score 0):

Found:

```
with cte
as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by FIELD_ONE, FIELD_TWO order by RECORD_ID desc) RowNumber
    from TestTable
)
delete cte
where RowNumber > 1
```

Comment: Good, now `ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Table_Fields UNIQUE (FIELD_ONE,FIELD_TWO)` so you don't have to do this again.