# "Syntax error in from clause" with nested query - MS Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        FullName
    FROM
        pr
    GROUP BY
        FullName
    HAVING
        COUNT(*)>=2
) T1
JOIN
    pr T2 ON T1.FullName = T2.FullName;
```

I used this answer to build this: [SQL Return only duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401326/sql-return-only-duplicate-rows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Although they didn't specify which DBMS they were using, I can assume it was not MS Access since it ran properly for them and not me.

Whenever I try to save this query, it says:

> Syntax error in FROM clause

Not sure where this is wrong. I know that access requires some weird brackets during joins but the problem is apparently with one of the FROM statements. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect an MS Access query to look like this:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (SELECT FullName
      FROM pr
      GROUP BY FullName
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
     ) AS T1 INNER JOIN
     pr as T2
     ON T1.FullName = T2.FullName;
```

Note the `as`s and `INNER`.

Comment: It was the `INNER` that did it. Frustrating that Access doesn't give better debugging messages. The extra `as` went unneeded however.

Comment: @Michael . . . The `as`s might depend on the version of MS Access.